# How to find difference between two epoch time stamps?

Tags: shell-script, timestamps, process-management

I am writing a script to kill a job which runs more than 30 minutes. My epoch time format is like **`1503935475067`** and I am using **`` current_time_stamp=`date +%s%3N` ``**

How to find difference between two epoch time stamps?

Comment: Are you asking how to do an arithmetic substraction? Is the problem that your shell (or the tools you generally use for arithmetic) only supports 32bit integers?

Comment: Or is it that you want the difference in number of UTC seconds as opposed to Unix seconds (86400th part of a day; varying in duration)?

Comment: Or is it that you want it in a `[[d-]hh:]mm:ss.mmm` format or other?

Answer (score 2):

With *bash* using [double parenthesis](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html):

```
date1=$(date +%s%3N)
date2=1503935475067

if  (( ($date1-$date2)/60000 > 30 )); then
    # do something
fi
```

Comment: Note that that syntax originated in `ksh`. You can also use `(( (date1-date2)/60000 > 30 ))` (also note that those timestamps are in miliseconds). That's actually better for cases where `date2` is negative as the `123--234` would cause an error in some shell because of that improper use of the decrement operator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer if i am trying to store the difference in a variable its throwing an error i tried in two ways like this time_diff=`(( (date1-date2)/60000  ))` and time_diff=(( (date1-date2)/60000  ))               syntax error near unexpected token `('
`time_diff=(($date1-$date2)/60)'

Comment: Use `time_diff=$(( ($date1-$date2)/60000 ))`